# Value Bundle of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

Below is my response from server

```
    [
{
"updates":[
{
"id":6,
"name":"Food Express",
"photo":"http:\/\/www.abc.org\/development\/data\/restaurant\/1451480096.jpg",
"updates":"testing updatessss"
}
],
"count":0
},
{
"updates":[
{
"id":96,
"name":"Madras cafe",
"photo":"http:\/\/www.abc.org\/development\/img\/res-bg.jpg",
"updates":"asdfasdfsafasdfsa"
},
{
"id":96,
"name":"Madras cafe",
"photo":"http:\/\/www.abc.org\/development\/img\/res-bg.jpg",
"updates":"vcxvzxvzx"
}
],
"count":4
}
]
```

Here is JSON response I Parse in the android but causes the error..

Here is my android code

```
  JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
       Log.e("Hello","Hi"+jsonarray);
         for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObjectmain = jsonarray .getJSONObject(i);
        JSONArray array = jsonObjectmain.getJSONArray("updates");
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length(); j++) {
         JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(j);
         String id = jsonObject.getString("id").toString();
         String name = jsonObject.getString("name").toString();
         String photo = jsonObject.getString("photo").toString();
         String updates = jsonObject.getString("updates").toString();

        }      
         }
```

I want to put this thing to the pushnotification over onMessage() method but i am not able to do so.

Here is my stacktrace...

```
07-02 13:08:53.553: W/System.err(19037): org.json.JSONException: Value Bundle of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
07-02 13:08:53.553: W/System.err(19037):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
07-02 13:08:53.553: W/System.err(19037):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
07-02 13:08:53.553: W/System.err(19037):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
07-02 13:08:53.553: W/System.err(19037):    at com.abc.ff.GCMIntentService.parseList(GCMIntentService.java:117)
07-02 13:08:53.553: W/System.err(19037):    at com.abc.ff.GCMIntentService.onMessage(GCMIntentService.java:63)
07-02 13:08:53.553: W/System.err(19037):    at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:223)
07-02 13:08:53.553: W/System.err(19037):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
07-02 13:08:53.553: W/System.err(19037):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-02 13:08:53.553: W/System.err(19037):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
07-02 13:08:53.553: W/System.err(19037):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Here is my `onMessage()` method...

```
@Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent data) {

        String message; 

         message = data.getExtras().getString("updates");

         Log.e("",""+data.getExtras().toString());

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
        parseList(data.getExtras().toString());

        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText(message).setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .getNotification();

        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(R.string.app_name, notification);

        {

            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            final PowerManager.WakeLock mWakelock = pm.newWakeLock(
                    PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                            | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "GCM_PUSH");
            mWakelock.acquire();
            notification.defaults|=Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;


            Timer timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    mWakelock.release();
                }
            };
            timer.schedule(task, 5000);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your response is missing a closing bracket ]

Comment: Updated. Thanks.. but still causes error

Comment: share your stacktrace

Comment: Shared please check @AshishRanjan

Comment: JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response); Here what is response ?

Comment: your response have syntax error... In last closing mission "]"

Comment: @Er.Arjunsaini : I already updated my response..

Comment: @RameshM.Bhati: Still not getting any response ? I think i received response from server in bundle form...

Comment: if your API (json) is called then you receive response, so can you give me response from your studio.

Comment: 07-02 13:43:12.240: E/=(19037): Bundle[{response=[{"updates":[{"id":6,"name":"Food Express","photo":"http:\/\/www.abc.org\/development\/data\/restaurant\/1451480096.jpg","updates":"testing updatessss"}],"count":0},{"updates":[{"id":96,"name":"Madras cafe","photo":"http:\/\/www.abc.org\/development\/img\/res-bg.jpg","updates":"asdfasdfsafasdfsa"},{"id":96,"name":"Madras cafe","photo":"http:\/\/www.abc.org\/development\/img\/res-bg.jpg","updates":"vcxvzxvzx"}],"count":4}], from=1087831256419, collapse_key=do_not_collapse}]

Comment: @RameshM.Bhati : It is the response which i am getting notification from server...

Comment: your json response is invalid. you can open this link- https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/  and put your responce and check.

Comment: @RameshM.Bhati : I checked that thing.. it is poerfect.. Remove Bundle and things from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're receiving a `Bundle` in your `GCMIntentService` which has a `JsonObject` and not a `JsonArray`. You should convert a `Bundle` to `JsonObject` like this :

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
Set<String> keys = bundle.keySet();
for (String key : keys) {
   try {
       json.put(key, bundle.get(key)); 
   } catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Then you can do your normal processing like this :

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(json.getString("response"));
Log.e("Hello","Hi"+jsonarray);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObjectmain = jsonarray .getJSONObject(i);
    JSONArray array = jsonObjectmain.getJSONArray("updates");
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length(); j++) {
         JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(j);
         String id = jsonObject.getString("id").toString();
         String name = jsonObject.getString("name").toString();
         String photo = jsonObject.getString("photo").toString();
         String updates = jsonObject.getString("updates").toString();

    }      
}
```

**UPDATE**

change the argument type of your `parseList` method from `String` to `Bundle`, so your parseList method should be like this:

```
parseList(Bundle bundle)
```

and replace `parseList(data.getExtras().toString());` with `parseList(data.getExtras());`

Now in your `parseList(Bundle bundle)` method, you can convert the bundle to json as described above.

Comment: 07-02 13:43:12.240: E/=(19037): Bundle[{response=[{"updates":[{"id":6,"name":"Food Express","photo":"http:\/\/www.abc.org\/development\/data\/restaurant\/1451480096.jpg","updates":"testing updatessss"}],"count":0},{"updates":[{"id":96,"name":"Madras cafe","photo":"http:\/\/www.abc.org\/development\/img\/res-bg.jpg","updates":"asdfasdfsafasdfsa"},{"id":96,"name":"Madras cafe","photo":"http:\/\/www.abc.org\/development\/img\/res-bg.jpg","updates":"vcxvzxvzx"}],"count":4}], from=1087831256419, collapse_key=do_not_collapse}]

Comment: Bundle[{response= problem here is it from server?

Comment: @AshishRanjan : I have to convert bundle in onMessage() method ?? is it ?? or I have to convert while parsing. ?

Comment: To be honest I am beginner in the android development so i don't know much right now.. I am getting error for the bundle.keySet(). I imported the bundle in file still not get it. @AshishRanjan

Comment: by bundle I mean, your `Bundle object` that you're receiving in `onMessage()`, replace bundle with your Bundle object, like if your Bundle object is response then use `response.keySet()`

Comment: @AshishRanjan : Can I update my `onMessage()` method in my question ??? so you can check

Comment: @AshishRanjan : I applied that thing.... Here is what i got
`org.json.JSONException: Value [{"updates":[{"id":6,"name":"Food Express","photo":"http:\/\/www.abc.org\/development\/data\/restaurant\/1451480096.jpg","updates":"testing updatessss"}],"count":0},{"updates":[{"id":96,"name":"Madras cafe","photo":"http:\/\/www.abcorg\/development\/img\/res-bg.jpg","updates":"asdfasdfsafasdfsa"},{"id":96,"name":"Madras cafe","photo":"http:\/\/www.abc.org\/development\/img\/res-bg.jpg","updates":"vcxvzxvzx"}],"count":4}] at response of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray`

Comment: change `JSONArray jsonarray = json.getJSONArray("response");` to `JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(json.getString("response"));` as in the updated answer.

Comment: @AshishRanjan : Yes I got the response now.. Now i am trying to set Title based on that do I need to change on `onMessage()` method or somewhere ?? If you know that will be great ?? if possible

Comment: what's `set Title`? If you mean setting the notifications title then no, you dont need to change anything for that

Comment: yes.. I want to setup the `.setContentTitle("Title")` and `setContentText(message)` from the response and image as well so i want to do from `ParseList()` or somewhere else ?? is there any way ?

Comment: i can tell you that, but it's not the correct way to ask a new question in comments, you should ask a new question for that.

Comment: btw yes, you can do it in your `ParseList` method

Comment: @AshishRanjan : It's verified... i am asking new question.. now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38158673/how-to-setup-setcontenttitle-and-setcontenttext-for-push-notification-from-json

Comment: @AshishRanjan : here it is my new question.. please check if possible

Comment: @AshishRanjan : I am looking forward to your reply at there.

Answer (score 1):

**Remove `Bundle[{response=` at the start from JSON from Response from serverside.**

if you want to from code than replace

```
 response.replace("Bundle[{response=","");
```

Comment: I received only parameters from a server not Bundle[{response= from serverside.

Comment: Bundle[{response= ?? You give anywhere LOG or SOP in code

Comment: No I still not give anywhere

Comment: @AnkitNagevadiya Please Just try One time...... Only replace your response like answer and try what happen