# How to setup setContentTitle and setContentText for Push Notification from json data

Tags: java, android, json, push-notification

I received the response from the server and I parsed that response in the android now I have to set the Notification Title and Text from that response. I means from that particular function.

Here I am putting my `ParseList()` function here where i parsed my response.

```
 private void parseList(Bundle bundle) {

        String id,name,photo,updates;

          try {
              JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
              Set<String> keys = bundle.keySet();
              for (String key : keys) {
                 try {
                     json.put(key, bundle.get(key)); 
                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
              }

              JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(json.getString("response"));
             Log.e("","Hi"+jsonarray);
              for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                  JSONObject jsonObjectmain = jsonarray .getJSONObject(i);

                  JSONArray array = jsonObjectmain.getJSONArray("updates");

                  for (int j = 0; j < array.length(); j++) {
                       JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(j);
                         id = jsonObject.getString("id").toString();
                        name = jsonObject.getString("name").toString();
                        photo = jsonObject.getString("photo").toString();
                        updates = jsonObject.getString("updates").toString();

                  }      
              }
          } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
          }
         }
```

There is a parameter called name,updates and photo. Now i have to setup the Notification Title from this response How can i set up that thing.. ?

I have `onMessage()` method with me but how can i put that values into that. ??

Here is my onMessage() method for Notification...

```
@Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent data) {

        String message; 

         message = data.getExtras().getString("name");


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
        parseList(data.getExtras());

        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentTitle(message)
                .setContentText(message).setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .getNotification();

        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(R.string.app_name, notification);

        {

            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            final PowerManager.WakeLock mWakelock = pm.newWakeLock(
                    PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                            | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "GCM_PUSH");
            mWakelock.acquire();
            notification.defaults|=Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;


            Timer timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    mWakelock.release();
                }
            };
            timer.schedule(task, 5000);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first your notification message must contains the values in different keys.

```
array( "title" => $title, "message" => $message )
```

the above code is php server side sample array data which is actually being added to `'data'` key and then the data is sent to applications using the different servers. I have used GCM and while receiving data from server message get the above key data from bundle.

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message).setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .getNotification();
```

here you can check that `setContentTitle` is used to add "title" and `setContentText` is the "subTitle" or message

Comment: sir you need to implement the server side code or android code. A bit confused from above answer comments. As i can see that you are reading data from 'name' key data sent via notification_message.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `NotificationCompat.Builder` to set the title, icon, content etc. for a notification. Here's an example:

```
private NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.whitelogo)
                    .setLargeIcon(anImage)
                    .setContentTitle(title); //set smallIcon,largeIcon, contentTitle for your notification.
```

and to add the notification :

```
Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                          .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                          .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                          .setContentTitle(message)
                          .setContentText(message)
                          .setContentIntent(pIntent); 

notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID_NOTIF, notification.build());
```

**UPDATE**

It's not working in your case because, there's no `String` with key `name` in your `bundle`, so this will return null :

```
message = data.getExtras().getString("name");
```

so move your notification code in the `parseList` method, as there you have already extracted all the values (id,name,photo,updates).

Comment: I setup at there.. but when pass the data value into it. it is not working..

for ex: `String message = data.getExtras().getString("name")`
`.setContentTitle(message)`

It is not working i already tried.

Comment: i tried same code in that and it is not giving a text in notification

Comment: to set the text `setContentText` is used, `setContentTitle` is used to set the title.

Comment: Notification I am getting but the text which is coming from server is not showing with that.

Comment: use `setContentText` for setting text as mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: It is not showing nothign in Title as well. Totally blank

Comment: you must be doing something wrong, please share your code where you're using `NotificationCompat.Builder`

Comment: `Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
    .setContentTitle(message)
    .setContentText(message).setContentIntent(pIntent)
    .getNotification();`

Comment: what are getting then in the notification? just the image?

Comment: it would be great if you could add all the notification related code in your question.i.e, the function where you're doing all this

Comment: `.getNotification()` is deprecated, you should use  `.build()` instead : `Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(this) .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher) .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()) .setContentTitle(message) .setContentText(message).setContentIntent(pIntent); notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID_NOTIF, notification.build());`

Comment: `manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID_NOTIF, notification.build());` got error in this line.. The method build() is undefined for the type of notification.

Comment: looks like you didn't change this line : `Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(this) .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher) .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()) .setContentTitle(message) .setContentText(message).setContentIntent(pIntent);`

Comment: Yes It is working... Thanks... setSmallIcon contains INT but photo variable contains the value in string how it works ??

Comment: photo variable contains the url of the image, as a `String`, you cannot set this as the icon. You need to download the image, if you've to set this image as the icon, else you can set some drawable image as the icon like this : `R.drawable.someImage`

Comment: Thank you so much... Really appreciate